# How to control desktop applications over SSH

Tags: ssh, desktop, remote

Assuming that the wife is *right now* using our desktop Kubuntu machine, probably surfing the web in Firefox or using Digikam. After logging into the machine via SSH, what can I do to 'pop up' little things to make her smile?

I've already figured out that `notify-send "Hi Ety"` will pop up KDE's messaging system and that she'll get the message. Is there anything else I can do, such as maybe start playing a song that she likes with Amarok? I'm not sure if `amarok -e /some-song.mp3` is actually getting sent to Amarok on her desktop.

Any other ideas? Anything from the mildly annoying to the very sweet would be appreciated!

Comment: I would try changing her desktop background. Not sure how to accomplish this from within KDE, though. I never liked KDE enough to use it.

Comment: A suggestion regarding the question itself: please edit the title to make it more relevant to others (e.g. "How to control Desktop applications via SSH").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the necessary authorization (via `Xauth` et al. which apparently you already do) you can control which desktop X applications show up on via the `DISPLAY` variable or the corresponding option. The default is usually `:0.0` which translates to the console on anything resembling a modern Linux distro.

Comment: Thank you! I'm experimenting now to see which `DISPLAY` value that I need to use.